# OutOfMemory error when sliding through multiple images in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, out-of-memory

I am using a ViewPager object within an Activity. This viewpager works as a gallery that shows multiple types of fragment (TextFragment which shows only a text, ImageFragment, VideoFragment, etc.).

I am using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter which from what I've gathered (and saw by myself) frees the previous elements of the viewpager as you navigate through them.

If I just slide normally through the gallery it works fine, watching the LogCat shows memory being allocated and deallocated properly (at least, it seems proper to me). But if I slide too fast through the gallery, it seems as though the VM is not capable of freeing memory fast enough and I end up getting an OutOfMemory Exception.

Is there any way to prevent this?

This is where I initialize my activity.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(currentItem);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);

        CirclePageIndicator indicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator = indicator;
        indicator.setViewPager(mPager);
 }
```

And this is my Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return multimediaList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Multimedia m = multimediaList.get(position);
            if (m.getTipo() == MMType.Imagen) {
                ImageFragment ifragment = new ImageFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("id", m.getId());
                ifragment.setArguments(bundle);
                return ifragment;
            }
            else if (m.getTipo() == MMType.Video) {
                VideoFragment ifragment = new VideoFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("id", m.getId());
                ifragment.setArguments(bundle);
                return ifragment;
            }

            else if (m.getTipo() == MMType.LabeledImage) {
                LabeledImageFragment ifragment = new LabeledImageFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("id", m.getId());
                ifragment.setArguments(bundle);
                return ifragment;

            }
            else if (m.getTipo() == MMType.Texto) {
                TextFragment ifragment = new TextFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("id", m.getId());
                ifragment.setArguments(bundle);
                return ifragment;

            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I currently have the same problem. Apparently efficient image handling needs to be programmed into you apps: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html, looking at BitmapFun developer demo to understand how to do this.

Comment: well this is a bit of a letdown, you would think by now Android would have solved Bitmap memory problems somehow :$